# Discord bot add role

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to add a mute command

This is my current code:

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Admin')) {
   let target = message.mentions.members.first;
   let role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "muted");

   target.roles.add(role);

   message.channel.send('${user} has been muted by ${message.author.username}');
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> (node:11052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I recommend you use `Roles#has` for searching for a member role

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('role-id') { ... }
```

2. `Collection#first` is a method, not a property, add `()` to `first`

```
let target = message.mentions.members.first();
```

You are getting `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` because you did not properly acces the first mention

Here is all the code fixed and put together:

```
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('ROLE-ID-HERE')) {
   let target = message.mentions.members.first();
   let role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "muted");

   target.roles.add(role);

   message.channel.send('${user} has been muted by ${message.author.username}');
}
```